# Primefaces Datatable how to make a column selected from bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to make a primefaces datatable column selected from bean

```
  <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{dtColumnsView.cars}" 
     widgetVar="carsTable" filteredValue="#{dtColumnsView.filteredCars}">                    
     <p:columns value="#{dtColumnsView.columns}" var="column" 
     columnIndexVar="colIndex" sortBy="#{car[column.property]}" filterBy="#
     {car[column.property]}">
     <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{car[column.property]}" />
     </p:columns>
   </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: You can't select columns... not in any way (at least not as part of the component)